# Multiple Brush Instances when using plotly function highlight () in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, crosstalk

I have a Shiny app that allows clustering of data using reactive variables and k clusters in the resulting plot and further highlight certain markers in the plot by search or highlight.

Whenever I change the variables or K clusters it results in more instances of Brush in a shiny app.

An example is as below as well as an image of the output . How to avoid this behavior of multiple Brush  instances and the SharedData titles in the shiny environment and just maintain one Brush and search box as in the examples [here](https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html#graphical-queries)?

```
  library(shiny)
  library(plotly)

 ui <- fluidPage(
       selectInput(inputId="Var1",choices=names(iris),label="Variable1"),  
       selectInput(inputId="Var2",choices=names(iris),label="Variable2"),  
       sliderInput(inputId = "sliderClust",  label = "Number of Clusters:",
                    1, min = 1, max = 3, step = 1),  
        plotlyOutput(outputId = "ClustGraph")
      )




  server <- function(input, output, session) { 

             K_Clust <- reactive({
                        selectedData <- iris[, c( input$Var1, input$Var2)]
                     kmeans(na.omit(selectedData), centers = input$sliderClust, iter.max = 10)
                   })


            x2 <- reactive({
                      selectedData <- iris 
                      selectedData[,input$Var1]
                     })

            y2 <- reactive({
                     selectedData <- iris 
                     selectedData [,input$Var2]
                     })

            output$ClustGraph <-renderPlotly({
                             req(input$Var1)
                             req(input$Var2)  

                           selectedData <- iris   
                           selectedData$Group <- as.factor(K_Clust()$cluster)

                           key <- highlight_key(selectedData, ~Species) 

               base <- plot_ly(key, x = x2(), y = y2(), 
                          type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', color = selectedData$Group,
                           hoverinfo = 'text',
                                 text = ~ paste(
                                                 Species,
                                               '<br>',paste0(input$Var1),':',
                                                 x2(),
                                               '<br>',paste0(input$Var2),':',
                                                 y2()
                                          ))
                      base %>% highlight(on = "plotly_selected", dynamic = TRUE, selectize = TRUE,
                               opacityDim = 0.5, persistent = TRUE)
                                        })
        }

   shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Undesired Output]

EDIT:

After further research on the issue I have come across these links but none offers a solution of maintaining one Brush instance

[multiple selectize/dynamic color brushes rendered in shiny](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1584)

[R Shiny reactive selectize highlight input in a plotly plot](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-shiny-reactive-selectize-highlight-input-in-a-plotly-plot/34480)

[Why does shiny App add a spurious widget to a Plotly graph using highlight function and selectize=TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583349/why-does-shiny-app-add-a-spurious-widget-to-a-plotly-graph-using-highlight-funct)

Comment: Hi I don't know what your problem is.  Please clarify.

Comment: the problem is that when I change values SelectInput widgets I get multiple Brush Color and SharedData instead of these features being displayed once
Have you tried to run the code on shiny environment ?

Comment: It seems that it has to do with `selectize`.. I cross-posted this issue in https://community.plotly.com/t/in-shiny-app-highlight-function-with-selectize-create-multiple-shareddata-boxes/45870

Comment: I guess, the problem is that each time you trigger `renderPlotly` (e.g. via your `selectInput`) a new plotly object and a new `SharedData` object is created. To avoid this you need to stop re-rendering your plot by e.g. using `plotlyProxy` which modifies the existing plot.

Comment: @ismirsehregal would you kindly show this solution by a simple example?

Comment: I don't have a specific answer you are looking for but I found this [talk](https://talks.cpsievert.me/20191115/#25) helpful in solving a similar brush issue I was having. I needed to add dragmode to the plot.